# database insertions in doInBackground

Tags: android, database, android-asynctask

I am extracting JSON data and inserting it into my SQLite database. I have written the database insertion code in another class and its instance is called in the doInBackground function, but i am getting some errors while doing so. My AsyncTask code is as follows.

```
package com.project.attendancemanager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;   
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

EditText username, password;
Button submit;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private static String KEY_SUCCESS="success";
private static String TABLES="tables";
private static String T_NAME="tname";
private static String T_DATA="tdata";
private static String TEACH_ID="TeachID";
private static String TEACH_NAME="TeachName";
private static String TEACH_USER="Username";
private static String TEACH_PASS="Password";
private static String CS_ID="CSID";
private static String CLASS_ID="ClassID";
private static String SUB_ID="SubID";
private static String CLASS_NAME="ClassName";
private static String COU_ID="CouID";
private static String COU_NAME="CouName";
private static String SUB_NAME="SubName";
private static String SEM_NAME="SemName";
private static String STUD_ID="StudID";
private static String STUD_NAME="StudName";
private static String STUD_USER="Username";
private static String STUD_PASS="Password";

DBHandler db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.loginET);
    password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordET);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBT);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new LoginDetails().execute();               
        }
    });
}

class LoginDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog=new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Retrieving Data...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String user=username.getText().toString();
        String pass=password.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(pass);
        UserFunctions userFunctions=new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json=userFunctions.loginUser(user, pass);

        try{

            if(json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS)!=null){  
                String res=json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                if(Integer.parseInt(res)==1){
                    JSONArray tab=json.getJSONArray(TABLES);

                    //For TeacherTB data extraction
                    JSONObject TeacherTBJson=tab.getJSONObject(0);
                    String TeacherTB=TeacherTBJson.getString(T_NAME);
                    System.out.println(TeacherTB);
                    JSONArray tdata1=TeacherTBJson.getJSONArray(T_DATA);
                    JSONObject teachdata=tdata1.getJSONObject(0);
                    String teachID=teachdata.getString(TEACH_ID);   //TeachID data extraction
                    System.out.println(teachID);
                    String teachName=teachdata.getString(TEACH_NAME);   //TeachName data extraction
                    System.out.println(teachName);
                    String teachUser=teachdata.getString(TEACH_USER);   //Username data extraction
                    System.out.println(teachUser);
                    String teachPass=teachdata.getString(TEACH_PASS);   //Password data extraction
                    System.out.println(teachPass);
                    db.insertTeachTB(teachID, teachName, teachUser, teachPass);
                    //publishProgress(teachID, teachName, teachUser, teachPass);

                    //For ClassSubTB data extraction
                    JSONObject ClassSubTBJson=tab.getJSONObject(1);
                    String ClassSubTB=ClassSubTBJson.getString(T_NAME);
                    System.out.println(ClassSubTB);
                    JSONArray tdata2=ClassSubTBJson.getJSONArray(T_DATA);
                    System.out.println(tdata2.length());
                    JSONObject classSubid=tdata2.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray classSubidArr=classSubid.getJSONArray(CS_ID);
                    JSONArray classIDArr=classSubid.getJSONArray(CLASS_ID);
                    JSONArray subIDArr=classSubid.getJSONArray(SUB_ID);
                    JSONArray teachidArr=classSubid.getJSONArray(TEACH_ID);
                    for(int i=0;i<classSubidArr.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONArray classSubidArray=classSubidArr.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONArray classidArray=classIDArr.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONArray subidArray=subIDArr.getJSONArray(i);
                        JSONArray teachidArray=teachidArr.getJSONArray(i);
                        for(int j=0;j<classSubidArray.length();j++)
                        {
                            String csid=classSubidArray.getString(j);
                            String classid=classidArray.getString(j);
                            String subid=subidArray.getString(j);
                            String teachid=teachidArray.getString(j);
                            db.insertClassSubTB(csid, classid, subid, teachid);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("OOPS ERROR!");
                }
            }

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        db.insertTeachTB(values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }   

}
}
```

db is the instance of my DatabaseHandler class in which insertions occur.

Logcat is as follows:

```
    09-08 13:15:43.650: W/dalvikvm(1469): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a91ba8)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Process: com.project.attendancemanager, PID: 1469
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at com.project.attendancemanager.LoginActivity$LoginDetails.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:110)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at com.project.attendancemanager.LoginActivity$LoginDetails.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:1)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
09-08 13:15:43.850: E/AndroidRuntime(1469):     ... 4 more
09-08 13:15:46.860: I/Choreographer(1469): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.project.attendancemanager.LoginActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b1f87078 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:348)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at com.project.attendancemanager.LoginActivity$LoginDetails.onPreExecute(LoginActivity.java:76)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at com.project.attendancemanager.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:61)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)  
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-08 13:15:52.610: E/WindowManager(1469):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am a newbie to this kind of android programming, so any help will be appreciated. Thank you! CHEERS!

Comment: Null Pointer Exception on line 111. Which line is line 111?

Comment: What is line No 111 in `LoginActivity.java` ..???

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because at the time your database handler object (DBHnadler) db is referred, db is not initialized. You are performing your operations on an instance that is currently pointing to null.

Before you perform your insert, do this:

```
db = new DBHandler;
db.getWritableDatabase().insert(your_arguments);
```